How can I use a thread pool to enable parallel processing in my Rust search application?
I'm working on a Rust application that searches for a query string in a file, and I want to utilize a thread pool to perform the search in parallel. Below is a simplified version of my code:
use std::error::Error;
use std::sync::{mpsc, Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

pub struct Config {
    pub query: String,
    pub ignore_case: bool,
}

fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    contents
        .lines()
        .filter(|line| line.contains(&query))
        .collect()
}
fn search_case_sensitive<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let query = query.to_lowercase();
    contents
        .lines()
        .filter(|line| line.to_lowercase().contains(&query))
        .collect()
}

pub fn run(config: Config, haystack: String) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let pool = ThreadPool::build(4)?;

    let results = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));

    let lines: Vec<&str> = haystack.lines().collect();

    for line in lines {
        let results = Arc::clone(&results);
        let query = config.query.clone();

        pool.execute(move || {
            let result = if config.ignore_case {
                search_case_sensitive(&query, line)
            } else {
                search(&query, line)
            };

            let mut results = results.lock().unwrap();
            results.push(result);
        });
    }

    Ok(())
}

pub struct ThreadPool {
    workers: Vec<Worker>,
    sender: Option<mpsc::Sender<Job>>,
}

impl ThreadPool {
    pub fn build(size: usize) -> Result<ThreadPool, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel();
        let receiver = Arc::new(Mutex::new(receiver));
        let mut workers = Vec::with_capacity(size);

        for id in 0..size {
            let worker = Worker::new(id, Arc::clone(&receiver))?;
            workers.push(worker);
        }

        Ok(ThreadPool {
            workers,
            sender: Some(sender),
        })
    }

    pub fn execute<F>(&self, f: F)
    where
        F: FnOnce() + Send + 'static,
    {
        let job = Box::new(f);
        self.sender.as_ref().unwrap().send(job).unwrap()
    }
}

impl Drop for ThreadPool {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        drop(self.sender.take());

        for worker in &mut self.workers {
            println!("Shutting down worker {}", worker.id);
            if let Some(thread) = worker.thread.take() {
                if let Err(err) = thread.join() {
                    println!("Worker thread panicked: {:?}", err);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Worker {
    id: usize,
    thread: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl Worker {
    fn new(id: usize, receiver: Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Job>>>) -> Result<Worker, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let thread = thread::Builder::new().spawn(move || loop {
            let job = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv();
            match job {
                Ok(job) => {
                    println!("Worker {id} got a job; executing.");
                    job();
                }
                Err(_) => {
                    println!("Worker {id} disconnected; shutting down.");
                    break;
                }
            }
        })?;

        Ok(Worker {
            id,
            thread: Some(thread),
        })
    }
}

type Job = Box<dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static>;

fn main() {
    let config = Config {
        query: "ha".to_string(),
        ignore_case: true,
    };

    let haystack = r#"
    This is a haystack,
    hahaha,

    nothing,

    ha

    lol
    "#
    .to_string();

    run(config, haystack);
}

I want to modify the run function to allow each line of the file to be searched concurrently using the thread pool. However, I'm not sure if I'm implementing the threading correctly, especially with respect to sharing results among threads and ensuring that all threads finish before returning from run.
In my current implementation, I create a ThreadPool and attempt to execute search jobs for each line of the file. However i get error below.
Error:
error[E0597]: `haystack` does not live long enough
  --> ***\src\main.rs:31:28
   |
26 |   pub fn run(config: Config, haystack: String) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
   |                              -------- binding `haystack` declared here
...
31 |       let lines: Vec<&str> = haystack.lines().collect();
   |                              ^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
37 | /         pool.execute(move || {
38 | |             let result = if config.ignore_case {
39 | |                 search_case_sensitive(&query, line)
40 | |             } else {
...  |
45 | |             results.push(result);
46 | |         });
   | |__________- argument requires that `haystack` is borrowed for `'static`
...
50 |   }
   |   - `haystack` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.


To pass a reference between threads, you'll need 'static; try to use String instead.
